Combine rows on multiple values removing null in SQL Oracle
I have calibrations logs for a piece of equipment. There are 3 calibration types that need to be logged daily, with failing results needing a retest.
Data can look like below in One day:



EQUIPMENT #
CALIBRATION
LOT
NUM RESULT
RESULT ASSESSMENT




1
HIGH
123
2
PASS


1
LOW
123
1
PASS


1
ROOM TEMP
NULL
74
PASS


2
HIGH
124
2
PASS


2
LOW
124
2
FAIL


2
LOW
124
1
PASS


2
ROOM TEMP
NULL
74
PASS



I need my columns to look like:



EQUIP #
LOT
CALIB HIGH
CALIBR LOW
ROOM TEMP
RESULT ASSESS




1
123
2
1
74
PASS


2
124
2
2
74
FAIL


2
124
2
1
74
PASS



I've tried using MAX but it omits the retakes.
select
equipment_#,
lot,
MAX(DECODE(calibration, 'ROOM TEMP', num_result)) Room_temp_result,
MAX(DECODE(calibration, 'ROOM TEMP', result_assessment)) Room_asessment,
MAX(DECODE(calibration, 'LOW', num_result)) low_result,
MAX(DECODE(calibration, 'LOW', result_assessment)) low_assessment,
MAX(DECODE(calibration, 'HIGH', num_result)) high_result,
MAX(DECODE(calibration, 'HIGH', result_assessment)) high_assessment
from table
group by 
equipment_#,
lot


tables are by nature unsorted, so ypur result can not be achieved with an ordering column

Assumptions:

If the LOT is NULL then it should be the maximum LOT for that EQUIPMENT#.
The tests stop after a PASS result so, for each EQUIPMENT# and LOT, should be ordered with FAIL first and PASS last and any rows without a test for high/low/temp should have a previous passing test that can be carried over.

If those assumptions hold then you can use:
SELECT equipment#,
       lot,
       LAST_VALUE(high_result) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
         PARTITION BY equipment#, lot
         ORDER BY rn
       ) AS calib_high,
       LAST_VALUE(low_result) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
         PARTITION BY equipment#, lot
         ORDER BY rn
       ) AS calib_low,
       LAST_VALUE(temp_result) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
         PARTITION BY equipment#, lot
         ORDER BY rn
       ) AS room_temp,
       LEAST(
         LAST_VALUE(high_assessment) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
           PARTITION BY equipment#, lot
           ORDER BY rn
         ),
         LAST_VALUE(low_assessment) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
           PARTITION BY equipment#, lot
           ORDER BY rn
         ),
         LAST_VALUE(temp_assessment) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
           PARTITION BY equipment#, lot
           ORDER BY rn
         )
       ) AS result_assess
FROM   (
  SELECT EQUIPMENT#,
         CALIBRATION,
         COALESCE(LOT, MAX(lot) OVER (PARTITION BY equipment#)) AS lot,
         NUM_RESULT,
         RESULT_ASSESSMENT,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY equipment#, calibration
           ORDER BY result_assessment
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(num_result) AS result,
  MAX(result_assessment) AS assessment
  FOR calibration IN (
    'HIGH'      AS high,
    'LOW'       AS low,
    'ROOM TEMP' AS temp
  )
);

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (EQUIPMENT#, CALIBRATION, LOT, NUM_RESULT, RESULT_ASSESSMENT) AS
SELECT 1, 'HIGH',      123,   2, 'PASS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'LOW',       123,   1, 'PASS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'ROOM TEMP', NULL, 74, 'PASS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'HIGH',      124,   2, 'PASS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'LOW',       124,   2, 'FAIL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'LOW',       124,   1, 'PASS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'ROOM TEMP', NULL, 74, 'PASS' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



EQUIPMENT#
LOT
CALIB_HIGH
CALIB_LOW
ROOM_TEMP
RESULT_ASSESS




1
123
2
1
74
PASS


2
124
2
2
74
FAIL


2
124
2
1
74
PASS



fiddle

Not sure this works if you have only 1 FAIL with or without ROOM TEMP per partition, but as often the poster doesn't give enough information about the possible data patterns to be sure a solution will always work.

If I got it right - you need high and low values per EQUIPMENT# for calibrations 'PASS' and 'FAIL' and the room temperature in the same row.
With your data provided and expected result - that could be done using conditional aggregaton to fetch PASS/FAIL lows and highs and
getting the temperature separately joining the subquery to the calibration results.
WITH   --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (EQUIPMENT#, CALIBRATION, LOT, NUM_RESULT, RESULT_ASSESSMENT) AS
      ( Select 1, 'HIGH',      123,   2, 'PASS' From Dual Union All
        Select 1, 'LOW',       123,   1, 'PASS' From Dual Union All
        Select 1, 'ROOM TEMP', NULL, 74, 'PASS' From Dual Union All
        Select 2, 'HIGH',      124,   2, 'PASS' From Dual Union All
        Select 2, 'LOW',       124,   2, 'FAIL' From Dual Union All
        Select 2, 'LOW',       124,   1, 'PASS' From Dual Union All
        Select 2, 'ROOM TEMP', NULL, 74, 'PASS' From Dual 
      )

Select    EQUIPMENT#, LOT, 
          Nvl(CALIB_HIGH, Max(CALIB_HIGH) Over(Partition By EQUIPMENT#)) "CALIB_HIGH", 
          Nvl(CALIB_LOW, Min(CALIB_LOW) Over(Partition By EQUIPMENT#)) "CALIB_LOW", 
          Avg(ROOM_TEMP) Over(Partition By EQUIPMENT#) "ROOM_TEMP", 
          RESULT_ASSESSMENT
From   (  Select    t.EQUIPMENT#, t.LOT, 
                    Max(Case When t.CALIBRATION = 'HIGH' Then t.NUM_RESULT End) "CALIB_HIGH", 
                    Min(Case When t.CALIBRATION = 'LOW'  Then t.NUM_RESULT End) "CALIB_LOW",
                    l.ROOM_TEMP, 
                    t.RESULT_ASSESSMENT
          From      tbl t
          Left Join ( Select EQUIPMENT#, NUM_RESULT "ROOM_TEMP" 
                      From tbl 
                      Where CALIBRATION = 'ROOM TEMP'
                    ) l ON(l.EQUIPMENT# = t.EQUIPMENT#) 
          Where     t.LOT Is Not Null
          Group By  t.EQUIPMENT#, t.LOT, t.RESULT_ASSESSMENT, l.ROOM_TEMP
       )
Order By  EQUIPMENT#, LOT, RESULT_ASSESSMENT 

/*      R e s u l t :
EQUIPMENT#        LOT CALIB_HIGH  CALIB_LOW  ROOM_TEMP RESULT_ASSESSMENT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------------
         1        123          2          1         74 PASS
         2        124          2          2         74 FAIL
         2        124          2          1         74 PASS              */

NOTE:
I used AVG() for ROOM_TEMP since that data doesn't have LOT defined and I'm not sure how many rows there are per the same equipment. If the data are realy as those provided it could be MIN() or MAX() - resulting the same.
There are more open questions regarding your actual data that should be described, though.
